# Is the Asset Browser going to support Collections?

Tags: collections, asset, asset-browser

I'm really enjoying Blender's 3.0 release specially the asset browser. However, I notice that I couldn't mark a Collection as an asset unlike the previous beta releases. Then found out Collections aren't supported. Will it ever be supported in the future? If so, will it be soon and why wasn't it included in the 3.0 release? Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your question is more focus for a developer than a Blender question and answer site, we are part of the community and we can only guess if this feature is going to be available.

Comment: Hi Emir. I see, sorry about that. Was hoping maybe someone with more experience with Blender's feature releases would have a general idea. Thanks for the reply and for letting me know. Hopefully it'll be supported soon. Thanks again.

Comment: The solution is to look on the Blender Foundation's web site and find the Asset Browser road map, which will tell you when various features will be supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collections are meant to be eventually supported and there is currently no schedule for which release they'll be in.  They didn't make the 3.0 release because the software to support them wasn't ready.

You can follow the asset browser project at [this devtalk page](https://developer.blender.org/tag/asset_browser/).

Comment: Oh thank you. That's great to hear, even if it means waiting longer. Better to have something fully working instead of rushed:)

Comment: @KisX Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I specifically avoided just saying "thanks" like I was advised, and was told I could still say thank you to anyone who have replied to me. I just wanted to thank the person for the reply. I didn't initally press the check mark as I noticed my question was closed so I didn't know what was the appropriate thing to do, also because I'm very new to the forum. Thank you

Comment: @KisX welcome to StackExchange and thank you for the upvote.  The exchange is a bit different than other Q&A sites, and takes some getting used to, but don't worry about making mistakes.  There are many helpful people here.